# Storing past relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a item tracking system which has an Item model which has a one to many relationship with an Invoice. Meaning that one invoice can have many items and an item can belong to one invoice.

I've now run into the need to return an Item into stock which for my system means setting the delivered boolean field back to false, but unless I set invoice_id to nil it will still show up as awaiting delivery to a customer and if I do nil it then my system will have no record of ever invoicing a customer for that item.

The only way I can see of this working well is to have a previous_invoices field that stores the ids of invoices its been on. Doing this would work from an Items point of view Item.previous_invoices would make sense but it would not show up in Invoice.items and to get the items which have been returned I would need to do a db search with a LIKE condition.

I'd rather not use a many to many association as it will only be the tiny fraction of items that are returned which need to use the table.

Is there anyway of doing this in rails or with a gem which can handle the finds on either side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between Invoice and Item **is** many-to-many, and you're just causing yourself difficulty by avoiding implementing it as such. The cleanest solution is an InvoiceItems table with something like a 'returned' field that you would check when you pull invoice items, perhaps with a conditional on the invoice's HABTM association with items.

Comment: I'm thinking this is how I'm going to have to do it, just going to be a pain to change the relationships over. I have a few months worth of items that need changing over. Im guessing the best way would be to create the new table then write a script to go through and create the right records using the invoice_id field as a reference

Comment: @Arcath, we've got a lot of code in a big project that's just there because it's so hard to refactor schema on a db shared between apps. That's bad, structural technical debt that's tough to pay back. If you still can refactor the schema, that's best.

Comment: I'm thinking a rake task should be able to sort it out, so if I modify all the code to support a many to many my current data should make it look like no invoices have items and then when I run the rake task it can create the records in the InvoiceItems table and restore the same data but with the new features